# YAML: Como utilizar a data atual na compilação do RMarkdown?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Como incluir a data atual do sistema de maneira automática no título do documento a ser compilado pelo `R-markdown`?

Quando eu tento incluir a data do sistema no campo `date` do YAML por meio do código: `r format(Sys.time(), "%d de %B de %Y")`, recebo uma mensagem de erro:

```
---
title: "Exemplo"
author: "Socrates"
date: `r format(Sys.Date(), "%d de %B de %Y")`
output: html_document
---

Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 3, column 7 found character that cannot start any token at line 3, column 7
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execução interrompida
```

*Nota: Pergunta e resposta [adaptadas do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown), para a sistemas com configurações de linguagem em português.*

Answer (score 4):

Para a data ser um campo válido no YALM, ela precisa ser uma `string`. Por essa razão, é necessário envolver o código do R em aspas. As aspas simples funcionam melhor do que as aspas duplas nesse caso (essas últimas podem causar erros quando a compilação é feita para `.docx` ou `.pdf`):

```
'`r format(Sys.time(), "%d de %B de %Y")`'
```

O YAML com o código acima produzirá no cabeçalho do seu documento um texto de data com o formato: "12 de novembro de 2020".

Repare também que é possível editar a ordem e o tipo dos componentes de data desejada, assim como o texto que acompanha a data. Por exemplo, é possível incluir o dia da semana com o elemento `%A`, produzindo o texto: "quinta-feira, 12 de novembro de 2020".

```
---
title: "Exemplo"
author: "Socrates"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%A, %d de %B de %Y")`'
output: html_document
---
```

Uma possibilidade, caso seu sistema esteja configurado em inglês e você for publicar o conteúdo em português, é utilizar apenas o mês no formato numérico, com o elemento `%m`. O código

```
'`r format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y")`'
```

produzirá (hoje, no dia que escrevo) o texto: "12/11/2020".

*Nota: resposta adaptada do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown) para a realidade brasileira, conforme as diretrizes sugeridas por [esse debate do SOpt Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3746/%c3%89-v%c3%a1lido-traduzir-uma-resposta-do-stackoverflow-em-ingl%c3%aas)*